# Isabelle/HOL proof by rule inversion

Tags: isabelle

I'm starting out with Isabelle/HOL and working through the `prog-prove.pdf` tutorial included in the distribution. I'm stumped in Section 4.4.5, "Rule Inversion". The tutorial gives (essentially) the following example:

```
theory Structured
imports Main
begin

inductive ev :: "nat ⇒ bool" where
ev0:  "ev 0" |
evSS: "ev n ⟹ ev (Suc (Suc n))"

notepad
begin
  assume "ev n"
  from this have "ev (n - 2)"
  proof cases
    case ev0 thus "ev (n - 2)" by (simp add: ev.ev0)
  next
    case (evSS k) thus "ev (n - 2)" by (simp add: ev.evSS)
  qed
end
```

This works, although I had to put the `notepad` around the proof because Isabelle didn't like `assume` at the top level. But now I would like to use the same proof technique by stating the same fact as a lemma, and this doesn't work:

```
lemma "ev n ⟹ ev (n - 2)"
proof cases
  case ev0 thus "ev (n - 2)" by (simp add: ev.ev0)
  (* ... *)
```

Isabelle stops at `ev0`, complaining `Undefined case: "ev0"`, and then `Illegal application of proof command in "state" mode` at the `by`.

What's the difference between the two ways of stating this goal? How can I use the above proof technique with the lemma statement? (I know that I can prove the lemma using `sledgehammer`, but I am trying to understand Isar proofs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cases` method tries to pick the right case analysis rule based on ”given facts”. Given facts are those that that you provide using `then` or `from` or `using`.

If you put your cursor on `have "ev (n - 2)"` you see this goal state

```
proof (prove): depth 1

using this:
  ev n

goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ev (n - 2)
```

while on `lemma "ev n ⟹ ev (n - 2)"` you get

```
proof (prove): depth 0

goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ev n ⟹ ev (n - 2)
```

The solution is to avoid meta-impliciation (`==>`) when you can use proper Isar commands to specify the assumptions of the lemma separately, and feed them to the proof using `using`:

```
lemma 
  assumes "ev n"
  shows "ev (n - 2)"
using assms
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried this `assumes`-`shows` style as well, but I ran into the same problem. The key to having the assumption actually used is the use of `using`. This use of `using` appears nowhere in my tutorial, so I had no idea. It works now. Although I do wonder why Isabelle would _not_ use assumptions by default...

Comment: It is actually quite common to have assumptions that are not used by the initial proof method, but somewhere inside the proof itself. You'll see that, too.